# Formatting in JSON

Tags: python, json, computer-science

I am trying to format a .JSON file so it shows what type of data it is.

This is my code thus far.

```
def createUser():          
    ProfileName = input("Profile Name »  ")

    if ProfileName in accounts.keys():
        print('\n')
        print(colored('Profile Name Exists Already..','red'))
        return createUser()
    Prof = ("Profile")
    Name = input("Name » ")
    Email = input("Email » ")
    Telephone = input("Telephone » ")
    Address1 = input("Adress » ")
    Zip = input("Postal Code » ")
    City = input("City » ")
    State = input("State(TX) » ")
    CC = input("Credit Card Number » ")
    EXP = input("EXP Date(MM/YYYY) » ")
    CVV = input("CVV » ")


    accounts[ProfileName] = Name,Email,Telephone,Address1,Zip,City,State,CC,EXP,CVV)
    autoSave()
    print(colored('Profile Saved Succesfully','green'))
```

When I run it it outputs this

```
["TEST", ["Tommy Smith", "tommy@gmail.com", "1234567890", "213 Clover ln", "75048", "Sachse", "NY", "2134545456787", "12/2020", "213"]]
```

I want it to output this

```
["Profile":"TEST", ["Name":"Tommy Smith", "Email":"tommy@gmail.com", "Number":"1234567890", "Address":"213 Clover ln","ZIP": "75048", "City":"Sachse", "State":"NY","CC": "2134545456787", "EXP":"12/2020", "CVV":"213"]]
```

Any ideas or help on how I could achieve this would be gladly appreciated.

Comment: Your desired output is invalid JSON. The top level is an array so there cannot be keys. Do you want to use an object instead?

Comment: If an object would make it work, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an associate array:

```
accounts = {"Name": name, "Email": email}
```